# Alternatives to db for user-logging operations into API contest

Tags: mysql, api, solr

I have a package of java rest APIs which get data from a solr index. The only interaction with database (mysql) is just for logging and to verify if a key, passed as a parameter through API, is still valid. Into db, the key is also related to a countdown which give information on the number of calls user can still do with that key.

I use connection pooling to interact with database, and I don't close connections after usage just to make them available again for other requests.I use autoReconnect = true when establish a new connection and a ping query to verify if it's still opened or database interactive_timeout is not over.

there is a way to avoid all of this? Can I get rid of a mysql database to manage this stuff without loss in performance?